# How to create a vbs to check for unread emails

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I am have been looking for ways on how to create a visual basic script for outlook and most of the suggestions have been from this website. Unfortunately none of them meet my exact need.

Reason for the script:

There is a shared mailbox which a few of my colleagues have access to and are meant to check however at times this can get ignored. I would like to create a script which checks for unread emails in this shared mailbox and emails specific contacts if the folder contains more than 10 emails.

What I have tried so far:

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub Main()
  Dim olMAPI As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Const FOLDER_TO_OPEN = "Mailbox - John Doe"   'Modify as appropriate

  Set olMAPI = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application") _
                          .GetNamespa   ce("MAPI")
  Call PrintFolderNames(olMAPI.Folders(FOLDER_TO_OPEN), "->")
  Set olMAPI = Nothing
End Sub

 Sub PrintFolderNames(tempfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, a$)
  Dim i As Integer
  If tempfolder.Folders.Count Then
     Debug.Print a$ & " " & tempfolder.Name & "  ";
     Debug.Print tempfolder.UnReadItemCount
     For i = 1 To tempfolder.Folders.Count
       Call PrintFolderNames(tempfolder.Folders(i), a$ & "->")
     Next i
  Else
     Debug.Print a$ & " " & tempfolder.Name & "  ";
     Debug.Print tempfolder.UnReadItemCount
  End If
 End Sub
```

I have tried to create a script first which checks for unread emails in a specific folder but this usually fails with syntax/run time errors. I have tried:

But this came back with a compile error then a syntax error.

I have also tried:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNamespace.Logon "Default Outlook Profile", , False, True    

Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Wscript.Echo colItems.Count

objOutlook.Quit
```

Comment: So, what exactly are the errors? Please don't make us guess.

Comment: It either returns a syntax error or a runtime 424 error. It usually highlights the Private Sub Main () for the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You must have outlook installed to use this code:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Const olMailItem = 0
dim objOutlook

call checkForUnreadMails


sub checkForUnreadMails()
    dim objFolder, objNamespace

    'get running outlook application or open outlook
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If

    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  

    'get inbox folder
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'send mail if more than 10 mails are unread
    if objFolder.UnReadItemCount > 10 then
        sendMail "your@mail.address"
    end if

    'send mail if more folder contains more than 10 mails
    'if objFolder.Items.Count > 10 then
    '   sendMail "your@mail.address"
    'end if
end sub

sub sendMail(address)
    dim oItem
    Set oItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With oItem
         .To = address
         .Subject = "Unread mails!"
         .Body = "You have too many unread mails!"
         .send
    End With
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Manu, please could you instruct me on where this is inputed. I have now installed Vs Express for Desktop 2013 but I have been informed that this could be entered in outlook by pressing ALT + F11.

Comment: Hi Manu, I have just tried to run this but I am being met with a 'Invalid Outside Procedure' error highlighting the 'Call checkForUnreadMails' when inputting this in Module 1 in Outlook (ALT+F11)

Comment: Oh, I thought you need a vbs-file... Try to create a new vbs-file and copy this code into it.

Comment: Thanks Manu, I have created the file and modified the appropriate fields (email address) and I am getting a Line 35 Char 50 Exoected 'End' error. Please assist.

Comment: I have edited the code a little... Try it again please, once without modifying the fields. It works for me...

Comment: Thank you for the time you are putting into this. I have tried the new modified script (unedited) however it is returning a different error code. This time I am getting Line 3, Char 7 Error: Name Redefined. Please assist.

Comment: I have modified this and removed the ol, this appears to have fixed it. This now works for my personal mailbox!!! Many Thanks

Comment: I would like this to look at the Shared Mailbox which goes by the name 'DB S' how do I get it to look there instead?